# How to scrape the text within a div if there's multiple divs with the same class name

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the amount of chapters in this manga using BeautifulSoup but the way it's contained is making it confusing:

[The Section]https://gyazo.com/c45fef82b0ce52dacd99d213538ab570)

I only want the Chapter number and not the content of the other divs. Currently I have (not the full code):

[The Website]https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-beginning-after-the-end

```
        chp = []
        temp = soup.select('section.pure-g entryBar > div.pure-1 md-1-5')
        for txt in temp:
            if "Ch" in txt.text:
                chp.append(txt.text)
```

How would I access the text within the first div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the structure of HTML, you can extract text from the first `<div>` under `class="entryBar"`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-beginning-after-the-end"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

ch = soup.select_one(".entryBar > div").text.split()[-1].strip("+")
print(ch)
```

Prints:

```
159
```

Comment: I definitely tried to make it more complicated than it needed to be, your code worked like a charm. Will accept the answer when I can!